# FindFit: getting confidence intervals for the returned parameters

Tags: fitting

I'm using `FindFit[]` to fit a function to some experimental data. I'd like to know what error bars are on the fitted parameters.

[Scipy's `curve_fit()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit) returns the optimised parameters along with their covariance matrix - is there anything equivalent for Mathematica? As far as I can tell, there's no mention of it in [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindFit.html).

Comment: You can likely use `NonlinearModelFit` which is basically `FindFit` with additional properties and diagnostics including parameter confidence intervals.

Comment: see [NonlinearModelFit](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html), [LinearModelFit](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearModelFit.html), and [tutorial /Statistical Model Analysis](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StatisticalModelAnalysis.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A fit performed using `NonlinearModelFit` has many properties including "CovarianceMatrix". For example, we can fit the function `A 2^(B t)` to the data `data = {{1, 2.1}, {2, 4.1}, {3, 9.2}}` with

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, A 2^(B t), {A, B}, t]
```

which estimates `{A -> 0.902745, B -> 1.1148}`.
We can access the covariance matrix of the estimated parameters using

```
nlm["CovarianceMatrix"]
```

yielding `{{0.00945806, -0.00530171}, {-0.00530171, 0.00307167}}`